# What is this old building in True Detective season 1 final episode?

Tags: true-detective

Does any one recognise what kind of building is this? It is half burrowed underground. Looks like a prison or military stronghold.

[image]

Comment: Are filming locations considered trivia? If not, I don't see why this should be closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The building is [Fort Macomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fort_Macomb). It is a 19th-century United States brick fort in Louisiana, build in 1922 as part of a defense plan after British forces invaded at the close of the War of 1812.The fort was occupied by Confederate forces in the Civil War.

[Link to article](https://www.vulture.com/2014/03/true-detective-finale-production-designer-fort-maze.html)